# How run Angular-CLI project on Apache php localhost:8888, not -prod version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am  new on Angular 2, and I am traing to run Angular-CLI  project on Apache **php localhost:8888**, but I cant do it. I run ng serve, but it run on localhost:4200, I put all my files in **htdogs** directory, change all html files to php (*index.php*), but still cant run project.  I can run Angular project when I make it by *npm start*, and with *system.config.server.js*.    Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command in your terminal:

`ng serve --port 8888`

This will order the lighttpd webserver that the angular cli uses to serve on the specified port 8888.

You can also use the shorthand `-p` as well.

---

You can find out this and more info on using the cli in the [official documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve).

Comment: I now about this, but the problem is that ng serve --port 8888 run lite-server, but I need run Angular on Apache.I use  php for back end.

Comment: Port 8888 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port

Comment: It is a bit difficult for me to understand exactly what you are trying to say, but if port 8888 is already in use then have you tried another port? For example `ng serve --port 9999`. This command is good for development only. In general though, since you edited your original post, it is quite clear you are renaming files. You shouldn't, don't change anything! To deploy the application to production just run `ng build --prod`. and copy the `dist` folder into `htdocs` folder.

Comment: THANKS for answer.   I want connect php back end to my angular front end. I run appache localhost:8888, all my angular project is in xamp/htdogs/myAngular  address. and when appach is runing index.html (or index.php), I cant see my  angular view,   because I did not run angular by ng serve.
I want to use angular for example  like Jquery. in my php.  I understand that I can access to  php back end  with http requests, but I want use <?php echo  "hello world"?> in my angular.   I hope  I  explain my  answer.   thank you again for understanding :))

Comment: @maninak I believe he's trying to run the angular project with `angular-cli`, doesn't matter the port number, as long as he is also able to connect to phpmyadmin on the apache server, which is also a problem I'm facing atm.